# How to get ID's of HTML element in a circular way?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html element:

```
<div class="child-elements-container">
    <div id="116" is-open="true">
        <div class="element">
        </div>
        <div class="child-elements-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="105" is-open="true" draggable="false">
        <div class="element">
        </div>
        <div class="child-elements-container">
            <div id="4" is-open="true">
                <div class="element">
                </div>
                <div class="child-elements-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which is this:

```
var movedElement = document.getElementById(movedElementId);
console.log(movedElement.parentElement)
```

I have an id number 4 which is movedElementId and with this, I want to reach ID 105.

So I would like to push 's ID'd to an array as an object that includes id and children. Something like this:

```
[
   { id: 116, children: {} },
   { id: 105, children: { id: 4, children: {} } }
]
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Your `children: {}` would be better defined as: `children: []` because obviously a *root* children's `[]`... you get the point.

Comment: it is better you can create objects with id, children tree. then create html's you want. that could be easier. otherwise you need to iterate whole DOM, since it has no depth level.

Comment: Yes, it is fine too, object or array I dont mind. But I would like to get the ID's in a similar way I described and efficiently. That's where I need help

Comment: If the markup represents a collapsible tree structure, I would use pure CSS classes, no ids are needed at all, and minimal scripting only.

Comment: But I need ID's. Using the object tree, I am going to do something else.

Comment: So you probably want to implement a classic recursive function to go over your elements, and descend down into their respective children. Have you done any research / reading-up on the principle of recursion yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick recursive function that extracts your wanted data from the html.

```js
const getChildren = (el) => {
  let kids = [...el.querySelectorAll(":scope>div")];
  let output = kids.map(k => {
    return {
      id: k.id,
      children: getChildren(k.querySelector(".child-elements-container"))
    }
  });
  return output;
};

let root = document.querySelector(".child-elements-container");
let out = getChildren(root);
console.log(out);
```

```html
<div class="child-elements-container">
    <div id="116" is-open="true">
        <div class="element">
        </div>
        <div class="child-elements-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="105" is-open="true" draggable="false">
        <div class="element">
        </div>
        <div class="child-elements-container">
            <div id="4" is-open="true">
                <div class="element">
                </div>
                <div class="child-elements-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```